# Как сделать запись в базе данных без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Как сделать запись в базу без перезагрузки с помощью AJAX?

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Имя"/>
    <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Текст"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) {

        // Переменные с формы
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

        $result = $data_base_CONNECT->query("INSERT INTO ".$data_base_TABLE." (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname')");

        if ($result == true) {
            $i = "Информация занесена в базу данных";
        } else {
            $i = "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
        }
    }

?>
```

JS

Comment: образцов того, как аяксом забросить данные формы, бексконечно много в сети, попробуйте что-нить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте себе постмен, там можно собрать нужный запрос. Примерно код будет выглядеть так.Подставляете свои параметры, свой класс кнопки

```
$('.button-class').click(function () {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://domain.com/path/to/script.php",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "param-key": "param-value" 
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
})
```